# Can I code absolute positioning elements of my website using Homestead sitebuilder?

Tags: css, html, web, css-position

I am creating a webpage with Homestead sitebuilder.

http://www.homeinspection247.com/free-real-estate-agent-marketing.html

I understand this may limit me as it doesn't seem to allow me to edit much of the html.

My problem is different elements, text, images, html, are positioned differently based on browser/resolution.

I believe Homestead uses "inline", not "blocked". I've read about the difference and I've read about using div to set container parameters.

I don't know if any of this is relevant. I am new to this forgive me.

I think I'm coming to the conclusion that I am limited by Homestead.

Is it possible to use a css/style sheet with Homestead? it seems I can only edit the head. I think everything I am talking about is coded outside of this?

Any help in the right direction for things to read about is much appreciated.

Comment: Wow, Homestead!  There's a site I haven't heard about in 15 years.  I wonder if my old Tripod account is still active.  Can you post some code that you have tried?  I'm not sure we're going to be able to help you write CSS if we can't see the HTML you're trying to style.

Comment: http://www.homeinspection247.com/free-real-estate-agent-marketing.html

Comment: your page is created completely by scripts, sooo can do pretty much.... nothing, if you want to build it your way, then u gotta start from scratch sorry.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I think the bigger issue is going to be the crap markup some WYSIWYG editor seems to be generating.  Have you seen this stuff?  `<div><font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" class="size12 Helvetica12" color="#000000"><br></font></div>`  It's straight out of FrontPage Express or something.  There don't seem to be any useful classes to attach styling to.

Comment: @Brad your right, but even if there was, anything he does will be a waste since its going to have to be changed at some point if he wants to implement his own idea's.

Comment: @Brad can you explain what is happening with my h1 tag at the top of the page so that it moves in different browser/resolution/device? Technical terms would be appreciated so I can research and learn.

Comment: @guybrianadams Your `<h1>` doesn't appear to do that.  At least, not for me.  In general, this would be called "responsive design", which is just a buzzword for building a page that can automatically lay itself out nicely on a variety of different devices and resolutions, usually facilitated by CSS media queries and the occasional bit of JavaScript.

Comment: If you're interested in learning about modern ways of building websites, you should probably ditch any kind of WYSIWYG editor and start coding your own markup from scratch. There are great tutorials on sites such as treehouse.com. Sorry if that doesn't answer your question, but it does sound like you're willing to put the effort in so you should look at doing things the right way.

Comment: Look at using a scaffolding framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which makes structuring a page very easy for a beginner. There are loads of free web hosting providers out there which allow you to fully edit all the source code, so ditch the 90s WYSIWYG provider and teach yourself a new skill.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-built styles and HTML attributes might override any CSS you could add, but according to http://www.homesteadconnection.com/Tut-CSSMenu.html, it might be possible to add a CSS file to your site. Use the FileManager to create it and upload it, then add this kind of code to the <head> of each page (to link to the CSS file you uploaded):

```
<link href="http://www.homeinspection247.com/files/CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My Homestead password probably expired in the last century too, so I can't test this. As others have said, if you were my client, I would probably advise you to switch your website to a more flexible solution, such as WordPress.